# Differentiating equations

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm an A-level student having trouble with approaching this question, looking at the mark scheme also gives no real tips on how to approach it, please help if possible.

[image]

Edit:

So when starting a) I looked at the equations and saw $h = \sqrt{l^2 -r^2}$, and $l=4/r$. I subbed l into the equation for height and got $h = \sqrt{(16/r^2) - r^2}$

...WAIT I think I got it! I just sub $h$ into the volume equation!

yeah if i do that i get $V = 1/3 \pi r^2 \sqrt{(16/r^2) - r^2}$, which simplifies to

$\pi/3 \sqrt{(16/r^2)(r^4) - r^2(r^4)}$

which simplifies to

$\pi/3 \sqrt{16r^2 - r^6}$

WHICH IS THE ANSWER!!

now for b):

since it's asking for a maximum and is asking for a relation between V and r is integration/differentiation but I don't know which one, nvm I should differentiate, when I do that I get:

i can't im getting stuck i feel dumb, im at $1/3 \pi (16r^2 -r^6)^{1/2}$

i forgot how to differentiate that, do i do every term e.g. $1/6 \pi (32r^1 -6r^5)^{-1/2}$

or something else?

edit:

Okay after doing a confusing differentiation i got to

$(\pi(32-6r^5))/(6\sqrt{16r^2 -r^6}) = 0$ for the maximum
that simplifies to $32-6r^5 = 0$ right?

then $6r^5 = 32$
$r = \sqrt[5]{32/6} = 1.40$ to $3$S.F but then the mark scheme says $1.52...$

EDIT:
AGAIN i made a nooby mistake

I'm at the answer of r = $1.52$

because of me not square rooting it by $4$ instead of $5.$

now I sub r into the
$\pi/3 \sqrt{16r^2 - r^6}$

and got $V_{max} = 5.197 == 5.2$ WHICH IS RIGHT!!!

FINALLY :D

Comment: Please share your approach or what in the mark scheme you don't understand and why so we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. Can you do part a)? What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: oh okay i made practically zero progress can you give me some time to try a decent approach?

Comment: @saulspatz should I delete this question and re-write it with an approach?

Comment: @CoderCody No, please edit the question to show your approach!

Comment: @CoderCody Not all.  Just edit it.

Comment: ill begin writing the approach to b)

Comment: @saulspatz im stuck at b)

Comment: @Ramanujan im stuck at b)

Comment: That's better!  Good job.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in `$` signs.  Also, you need to use `\sqrt`, `\pi`, `\log` and so on.  There are some fractions here that are ambiguous.  You can write `$\frac{1+2}{3+4}$` for example to get $\frac{1+2}{3+4}$.  Just do the best you can; people will edit your posts to improve the typesetting.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a relationship between $r,h,$ and $l$!  Use that, and use the other formulae.

That should solve part (a).

To solve part (b), differentiate $V=V(r)$ and find where it is zero $\cdots.$

Answer (score 1):

As it is a symmetric cone , it follows that $h^2=l^2-r^2$, where $l$ is slant height , $h$ is height and $r$ is radius of base . Also $rl=4.$ Therefor $l=4/r$.  Now part a) can
be easily solved .

For part b) , when $V$ is maximum , $V^2$ is also maximum , therefore $d(V^2)/dr = 0$. Therefore $d(16r²-r^6)/dr = 0.$ Solve and you will get the value of $r$ at which $V$ is maximum very easily .

Comment: thank you i took that approach but i didn't see it immediately, for some reason i looked up the equation for a cone and took that instead of A=pi x r x l which was this A=πr(r+sqrt{h^2+r^2}) and that just confused me.

Comment: wait so i only need to differentiate 16r^2-r^6? i thought id need to do the whole thing

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$